# Sci-fi/fantasy book trilogy (90s to 00s) where a science experiment gone wrong looses magic on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

What I remember about the series was that a science experiment went wrong (or maybe right?) and magic was loosed on Earth.

An adult brother is looking for his younger sister and when he finds her, she is being transformed by the magic.

I think I remember it being a trilogy of books.

Hoping this is familiar to someone because it is eating my brain alive trying to figure this out, lol. Google is no help.

Comment: I don't think there was a sister, but Stephen Boyett had a trilogy involving magic being loosed on Earth that started with *Ariel*.

Comment: Stephen Boyett: https://www.steveboy.com/writing.html

Comment: Thanks for responding but even though Ariel sounds interesting, this isn't the book I was referencing.

Answer (score 8):

Possible [Magic Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1239560.Magic_Time) by Marc Scott Zicree and Barbara Hambly.

[image: Magic Time]

> For rising young lawyer Cal Griffin, it's just another day in the Big City--until the lights go off...for good. Suddenly packs of pale crouched figures are stalking the darkened subways, monsters prowl Times Square, and the people all around Cal are...changing. Similar weirdness is happening everywhere, from the dank, cold heart of a West Virginia coal mine to a remote lab in South Dakota--where a team of government scientists has unwittingly invited something catastrophic into the world--to the highest levels of power in Washington, D.C. And Cal Griffin is not the only one struggling to comprehend the surreal, devouring chaos surrounding him--nor the only one who will be forced to accept a new role in this brave new world of nightmare and wonder. For the forces bled from the stilled machines are fuelling a consciousness both newly born and ancient--and more than one unlikely hero will be needed for the titanic battle between the darkness and the light.

I don't have the book to check, but [a review here](https://fantasyliterature.com/reviews/magic-time/) says:

> The hero’s young sister, Tina, for instance, morphs into something between a Smurf and a Tolkienesque elf.

which matches your memory of the protagonist's sister being transformed.

It is about magic being loosed on the world as the result of an experiment, and it is the first book in a trilogy. The timing is slightly late though as the book was published in 2001.

Answer (score 6):

You may be remembering the "Empire of the East" series by Fred Saberhagen. These novels are set in the far future on a post-apocalyptic Earth, where magic has been made possible because of the unexpected side-effect of a missile defense system. The missile defense machine, operated by a computer named ARDNEH, created a force field that inhibited nuclear explosions by changing the laws of physics within its sphere of influence; this change allowed magic to exist, and transformed explosions that occurred simultaneously with the field's influence into living energy demons.
The protagonist's adopted sister is kidnapped by the villains.

[image]